# Count Overlapping Lines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, line, overlapping-features

I'm trying to calculate the frequency of overlapping lines.

The question is pretty identical to the illustration show here [Frequency of partially or fully overlapping lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67208/frequency-of-partially-or-fully-overlapping-lines)

However I have no python programming skills, so any advice or guidance on achieving a similar result would be a great help.

I'm using ArcGIS 10 Basic.

Comment: I'd look at overlay events from Linear Referencing as suggested in [my answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67209) to the question that you linked to.

Comment: The answer I outlined at the question I linked as a possible duplicate uses Intersect with Summary statistics. Your use case, particularly with partial overlap, may require summarizing based on an *original* segment ID, rather than intersected segment IDs depending on what you're looking for - how many times your existing lines overlap at *any* point vs specifically which segments overlap how many times. A spatial join of the lines to themselves with the appropriate method (like crossed by outline or boundary touches - intersect won't work) and then checking the join count field may also work.

Comment: I just tested the solution of @ChrisW and found that works and will be easier to implement than my suggestion.  Perhaps keep Linear Referencing in reserve for any more complex requirements that may emerge from your work.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys. I will explore Chris W.Solution & come back with more questions if I need further assistence.