# How to render overlapping bus trips as one route from OSM?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, tilemill, cartocss

I would like to create bus map for my city from OSM data.

I imported data into Postgresql with osm2psql and I can render routes with Mapnik. But the problem is that same route ref is shown multiple times and very close together.

I think this is because each bus route is made from multiple trips.
For example bus line 4 has 11 different stop combinations but most of them go through same stops only in different order.

[image: Multiple route names in same route]

My question is how to avoid repeating name of the same route multiple times by any means necessary. (preprocessing XML, different SQL, carto css attributes)
I found a post about[Overlapping lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/rendering-overlapping-lines) but this are lines from different routes and a different problem.

I fixed this a little by select distinct(way) but it isn't great.

I found out about ST_DIFFERENCE Postgis function but I don't know how to construct SQL that would create difference of all different trips on same route joined them and represents them as one.

I read [similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mapnik/CEuWNVJ9SLQ/RhPsioIBnYEJ) and added `text-clip:true` and `text-avoid-edges:false` to `#Routes`, `buffer-size:768` to `Map` and  changed MetaTile to 8 with no visible differences.

I render map with Tilemill with this cartocss:

```
#Routes {
  line-width:1.5;
  line-cap: round;
  ::labels {
    text-name: "[ref]";
    text-face-name: "Trebuchet MS Regular";
    text-placement:line;
  }
}
```

I select bus routes from DB like that:

```
(select distinct on (way)   way, ref from planet_osm_line WHERE "route" = 'bus'  order by way, ST_LENGTH(way) DESC) as buses
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `select distinct` (which would not work, because all routes differ slightly, even if for a direction), use `select ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(way)) as way, ref from ... where ... group by ref`.