# Creating parallel lines in MULTILINESTRING table using Postgis?

Tags: postgis, polyline-creation, parallel-lines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create one-sided buffers or parallel lines in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/how-to-create-one-sided-buffers-or-parallel-lines-in-postgis)

I need to make parallel lines on a MULTILINESTRING table, similar to st_buffer, but that the result come be lines, not polygons. I saw some posts about the st_offsetcurve function, and I thought this is the solution to my problem, but I didn't see this function on Postgis 1.5! Sorry for my question, I'm a new Postgis user!

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/how-to-create-one-sided-buffers-or-parallel-lines-in-postgis

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to add the offsetCurve-RafalMagda.patch to Postgis's functions.