# Achieving Flat-End line buffers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I need to buffer a series of lines by 40m, however I only want the buffer to come off the sides and not off either end of the line.

I know in ArcGIS there is a "flat-ends" tickbox that achieves exactly this, however unfortunately I can't use ArcGIS at this current time.

Is there any way to achieve this in QGIS?

I've had a look at some of the work arounds, but due to the scale of my datasets (national road networks) none of the ones I have found so far are feasible.

Comment: Not sure what format your data is, but looks like you may be able to do it via PostGIS statement, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/how-to-create-one-sided-buffers-or-parallel-lines-in-postgis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the v.buffer tool in the `Grass Commands` toolsets, you can make a flat buffer.

There there are two choice boxes
[image: v.buffer]
If you have `Make outside corners straight` set to `No`, and `Don't make caps at the ends of polylines` as `Yes`, the result should be similar to the ArcMap straight edge buffer.

The following are the 3 combinations of the above two checkboxes, note the binary combination in the layer name (0 = no, 1 = yes). 
[image: v.buffer results]

You should probably also run a topology fixer/cleaner before, the Grass tool tends to return funny results if the topology isn't perfect

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I needed, had no idea QGIS had those GRASS commands squirreled away.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: NB: Is there any way to ensure that the buffers created are individual polygons and not dissolved into one giant polygon?

Comment: I am also interested in getting individual polygons and not one dissolved polygon. IS this possible?

Answer (score 3):

OpenJUMP may not suit you because all data must fit in memory but with 64 bit jre the limit is rather high. Most important, it can.

[image]

Comment: OpenJUMP's buffer tool accomplished this better than QGIS or Esri!

Comment: Just saying thanks for presenting me a software that appears to be much faster in many of these fundamental algorithm! :D

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the same result can be achieved directly with `ST_Buffer()` by using a flat endcap with a round join, as follows:

```
ST_Buffer(linestring_geom,<buffer_radius>,'endcap=flat join=round')
```