# Flat-ended buffers on touching polygon features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer

Please note that emphasis is on POLYGON here NOT POLYLINES!

I need

- Buffer/s on one polygon,
- with two touching features
- and straight touching parts after difference has been applied

I do not want this result:

[image]

but, rather something like this (the solid black lines, I've scribbled over the lines I don't want in blue)

[image]

I need the buffers to end at the **shortest line between the buffer boundary (of the union of the features), and the exterior ring intersection points of the two features**.

This solution does not work for Polygons as far as I attempted: [How to achieve “Flat-End” line buffers in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115687/how-to-achieve-flat-end-line-buffers-in-qgis)

Comment: i've edited the question, although I'm sure it's a duplicate, but I can't find the original :-/